# How do I go back in controller?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zend-framework2

I have  forms with id's `formularregister` and `formularadresa` and one button to submit with id `comanda`.

I want to submit both forms with one button (`<a type="submit" id="comanda" class="btn btn-default" onclick="submitForms()">Finalizare comanda</a>`) and go back to controller action (zend framework 2) to validate the values from post.

My JS function is this:

```
function submitForms() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#comanda").click(function() {
            $.post($("#formularregister").attr("afisarecos.phtml"), $("#formularregister").serialize() + $("#formularadresa").serialize(), function() {
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request to your controller action. You'll find a lot of [examples](https://www.google.fr/search?q=ajax%20ZF2) on the Web, but the most important parts to know for using Ajax in ZF2 are:

- Enable `ViewJsonStrategy` in your */module/Application/config/module.config.php*

  ```
  'view_manager' => array(
      // ....
      'strategies' => array(
          'ViewJsonStrategy',
      ),
  ),
  ```
- Ajax request in your *view*

  ```
  $.ajax({
      url : 'url/to/yourController/action',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data : fromData,
      async: true,
      success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
      {
         //success function
      }
      error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) 
      {
         // error function
      }
  });
  ```
- In your *controller action*

  ```
  if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) { //ajax call

      // your logic here

      $jsonModel = new JsonModel(
                     //...
      );

      return $jsonModel;

  }
  ```

Please see this [simple example (Code + Demo)](http://learnzf2.sitrun-tech.com/learn-zf2-ajax) for more details.